# SAMD21 ecrypted firmware

Tags: arm, bootloader, cortex-m, samd21

I'am working on SAMD21, but now I'd like to implement the possibility to ecrupted firmware. Is it possible on the SAMD21? I find this pdf this is exactly what I want to do page 36 but this for SAM3/4 [AT02333](https://www.microchip.com/content/dam/mchp/documents/OTH/ApplicationNotes/ApplicationNotes/Atmel-42141-SAM-AT02333-Safe-and-Secure-Bootloader-Implementation-for-SAM3-4_Application-Note.pdf)

I googled, but I found nothing for SAMD21, is anyone have a doc or maybe source code tutorial ? My idea is to encrypted my firmware with AES128, so I know I need to create implement that in bootloader but I've never done that...

Comment: if the chip doesnt do it what is the value?  are you wanting to encrypt field updates?  and in that case what value would there be in having it encrypted on flash?  if not build into the chip with a key that you control it doesnt add any security it simply adds more work/resources.

Comment: if you want to encrypt field updates (and decrypt on the way to flash) then just use a library to do the decryption.  same goes for code on flash but you would then need to run in ram and all the details to decrypt the secrets needed to decrypt the flash will be on the flash clear text.

Comment: it is best to just use the mcu with the features that you want, there are reasons why vendors have hundreds of different products.

Comment: @old_timer yes I want to encrypted my updated firmaware, upload my board with this encrypted firmware, just to prevent an easy user decompilation...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could implement firmware encryption on SAMD21 as well as a lot of other MCUs.
The idea of firmware encryption does not depend on exact chip or even MCU architecture. The main things are:

1. The manufacturer releases the new firmware and encrypts it.
2. The encrypted firmware is transmitted via public domain into the target MCU.
3. The target MCU decrypt the encrypted firmware and flashes it directly to the internal flash.
4. The target MCU should be locked to prevent reading decrypted firmware from the internal flash.

As you can see, there is nothing here about protocols, encryption methods, or microcontroller type - all this up to you. The main thing that is needed from the microcontroller is the presence of a protection bit and a memory area for the bootloader.
You could use any of the Safe and Secure Bootloader Implementation Tutorial and adopt it to SAMD21 accordingly.